# Why does my right elbow joint make a popping noise when I do pullups, pushups or dumbell curls?

Tags: injury

Everytime I do these exercises, specifically pull ups and push ups, I always hear a popping or cracking noise only in my right elbow for some reason. Even from stretching it, it still makes this sound.
Also, when I do forearm curls my right wrist only is always hurting.
Why is this?

Answer (score 1):

Crepitus, or crepitation, describes any grinding, creaking, cracking, grating, crunching, or popping that occurs when moving a joint.

If you experience those sounds then it does not necessarily mean anything is wrong. However, if those sounds are accompanied by joint pain or swelling, then there may be an injury that requires treatment.

I would see a doctor to get a diagnosis.